# Mockito mocking a Response class and reading with readEntity method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I need to mock a class that has a method that returns javax.ws.rs.core.Response. The class follows this method call with a .readEntity(String.class). I'm setting the Response as follows:

```
when(methodCall).thenReturn(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(someEntity).build());
```

Now when this Response is being read using response.readEntity(String.class); it throws an error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException : Method not supported on an outbound message.**

How can I set the Response in thenReturn so as to return an inbound message readable by the readEntity() method.

P.S. I can't make changes in the main class, only in test class.
I'm using java 1.8 with junit 4.12 and mockito-all 1.9.5, mockito-inline 3.8.0

The class I'm mocking:

```
Response response = client.target().request().header().post();
String entity = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code please, so we can see what's going on?  It's likely the error isn't actually on that line.  Incidentally, I wouldn't try to mix different versions of Mockito.  Don't use mockito-all 1.9.5 with mockito-inline 3.8.0, as Mockito has changed an awful lot between versions 1.9.5 and 3.8.0 - that's about 10 years worth of development right there.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but so as to say my hands are tied on the tech stack. I have to make it work on those versions itself.

Comment: Please check the updated question. Upon evaluating the Response line I get: Outbound.JARX.class[response{200 OK, Body}] and then in the next line I'm getting that error.

Comment: No, I'm serious.  Do NOT try to use versions 1.9.5 and 3.8.0 of Mockito together.  If that happens to work, it's more by good luck than good planning.  And you may have updated your question, but you haven't shown any more of your test than what you had previously.  Can you maybe show the entire test?  As I said earlier, it's likely that the error isn't actually on the line that you showed.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to be sure that the response is mocked:

```java
Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class)
```

Then I suggest you to mock `readEntity` in this way:

```java
Mockito.doReturn(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(someEntity).build())
       .when(response)
       .readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, although the Response object is only local to each method and is being created inside the method as follows: 'code'public void foo() { Response response = client.target().request().header().post(); String entity = response.readEntity(String.class);} 'code'

Comment: Mockito is unable to mock this local reference and it's throwing the same error as before. P.S. I'm  mocking "client" class in this scenario and want to return a Response object readable by readEntity() method.